# regex works in perl, fails to match in bash, works in zsh but BASH_REMATCH is empty

Tags: regex, bash, zsh

```
for d in "A - test1 (a)" "B - test2 (b)";
do
  if [[ "$d" =~ -\s(.*?)\s\( ]];
  then
    D="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    echo "$d --> $D : $BASH_REMATCH"
  else
    echo "NO MATCH $d"
  fi
done
```

In bash this outputs

```
NO MATCH A - test1 (a)
NO MATCH B - test2 (b)
```

In zsh, it fails

```
zsh: failed to compile regex: Unmatched ( or \(
```

If I modify the expression to `[[ "$d" =~ "-\s(.*?)\s\(" ]]` in zsh it matches but with no capture

```
A - test1 (a) -->  : 
B - test2 (b) -->  :
```

A Perl script with the same regex expression does work

```
$x="A - test1 (a)";

if ($x =~ /-\s(.*?)\s\(/) {
   print "$x -> $1\n";
} else {
   print "No match: $x\n";
}
```

This outputs `A - test1 (a) -> test1` as expected.

How can I make the regex work (extracting `test` from `A - test1 (a)` as per this example) in both bash and zsh?

Comment: In general, when using Perl, you have to use the Perl syntax for regexpes. When using bash, you have to use the bash syntax. In zsh, you have to use the zsh Syntax. If you would use Emacs, you would have to use the emacs syntax. Of course in zsh `BASH_REMATCH` is always empty; what makes you think that zsh would populate a variable with _bash_ in its name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash use `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s` and remove the `?`:

```bash
for d in "A - test1 (a)" "B - test2 (b)"; do
  if [[ "$d" =~ -[[:space:]]([^[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]\( ]]; then
    D="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    echo "$d --> $D"
  else
    echo "NO MATCH $d"
  fi
done
A - test1 (a) --> test1
B - test2 (b) --> test2
```

With zsh it is almost the same, except that you must use `match` instead of `BASH_REMATCH` and quote the final parenthesis of your regexp:

```
for d in "A - test1 (a)" "B - test2 (b)"; do
  if [[ "$d" =~ -[[:space:]]([^[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]'\(' ]]; then
    D="${match[1]}"
    echo "$d --> $D"
  else
    echo "NO MATCH $d"
  fi
done
A - test1 (a) --> test1
B - test2 (b) --> test2
```

Comment: `zsh: failed to compile regex: Unmatched ( or \(`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that this is the `bash` version. Fixed.